# Why do we need "var self = this" in classes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

Why can't we directly use `this` instead of `self` in the following example?

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}
```

After responses, I've learned:

Yes, there is no need if there is no context switch in class.

But I will use this approach as "convention" although there is no need.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's **no** reason why you can't use `this` directly there (and I would say it would be better for readability if you *did*).

However, the `var self = this;` is often needed in situations like the following (basically, any asynchronous action like event binding, AJAX handlers etc, where the resolution of `this` is deferred *until* it equals something else);

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(self.name); // otherwise, this is window; use self to keep a reference to the "SeatReservation" instance.
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Does setTimeout run in constructor? Or is it method of class?

Comment: @ozz: See the documentation for [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout); it delays the execution of the provided function for the number of milliseconds specified.

Comment: Not to mention, setTimeout also allows you to pass a parameter. i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/rYB3f/ which in your example, would remove the need to redeclare `this` as `self`.

Comment: @Gavin: Not x-browser unfortunately (IE for example).

Comment: Urgh, well spotted. I'm sure it used to be, however it appears not. Thanks for pointing that out Matt.

Answer (score 9):

It is usually done in order to keep a reference to this when the context is changing. It is often used in event handlers or callback functions. But as mentioned before, there is no reason to use it in your specific example.

You will find more details in the following article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations

Answer (score 5):

In your example code there is no reason at all to copy `this` to a variable.

It's usually used when the code uses a callback method. Inside the callback method `this` doesn't reference the object, so you use the variable for that.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, there is "no" reason for doing this.

There is however, situations where it will help you, although some may frown upon it's usage.

i.e.

```
$('a.go').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('busy'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('busy');
        $.ajax(
        {
            success : function(resp)
            {
                $(this).removeClass('busy');
            },
            error : function()
            {
                $(this).removeClass('busy');                
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the above, `$(this)` within the success and error callbacks would not reflect to the link you clicked, as the scope has been lost.

To get around this, you would do `var self = $(this)` i.e.

```
$('a.go').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('busy'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('busy');
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax(
        {
            success : function(resp)
            {
                btn.removeClass('busy');
            },
            error : function()
            {
                btn.removeClass('busy');                
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: although you are of course technical correct, answers like this trouble me a bit: **jQuery != javascript** ! Answering a broad javascript question with jQuery syntax may be confusing for beginners.

Comment: Your right however, beginners rarely learn native javascript, they tend to search Google for a solution, which in most cases results in using jQuery. It's a double edged sword. If I had of given a native javascript example, someone who only knows jQuery based javascript would be confused.

Comment: JQuery IS native javascript. It's not native DOM handling though. The confusion runs deep.

Comment: I know this is six years old, but where is the "self" in the second example?

Comment: @DJClayworth - In the above example, `var btn = $(this);` is the self. Ultimately you need to create a copy of `this` in the current scope before you use it in another (e.g. in the ajax response, where `this` is something completely different.) HTH?