# Calling a method from another method in the same class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why am I getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: self.myTest is not a function"? How do I call a method from within another method in a javascript class?

```js
class MyClass {

    myTest() {
      console.log('it works');
    }

    runMyTest() {
      self.myTest();
    }

}

var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.runMyTest();
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**You need to use the `this` keyword instead of `self`.**

```
runMyTest() {
    this.myTest();
}
```

**A side note**

If you are nesting standard functions notation then `this` is not lexically bound (will be undefined). To get around this, use Arrow Functions (preferred), `.bind`, or locally define `this` outside of the function.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.number = 3;
  }

  test() {
    function getFirstThis() {
       return this;
    }

    const getSecondThis = () => {
       return this;
    };

    const getThirdThis = getFirstThis.bind(this);
    
    const $this = this;
    function getFourthThis() {
      return $this;
    }

    // undefined
    console.log(getFirstThis());
    
    // All return "this" context, containing the number property
    console.log(this); 
    console.log(getSecondThis());
    console.log(getThirdThis());
    console.log(getFourthThis());
  }
}

new Test().test();
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `this` not `self` like

```
runMyTest() {
  this.myTest();
}
```

However a lot of implementations like to keep the reference and are doing the following:

```
var self = this;
```

That might be the reason you were thinking of `self` as self reference. For further reading I'd suggest this [SO - post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577241/why-do-we-need-var-self-this-in-classes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

```
class MyClass {

 myTest() {
  console.log('it works');
 }

 runMyTest = ()=>{
  this.myTest();  
 }

 runMyTest2 = function(){
  this.myTest(); 
 }
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.runMyTest();
myClass.runMyTest2();
```

use arrow function to bind this to the global object.  To represnt objects properties we have to use function

```
 let user = {
    name :"Something"
 }

 user.value = ()=>{
   console.log(this)
 }

 user.value2 = function(){
   console.log(this)
 }

   user.value(); ///returns this for windows
   user.value2(); ///returns object user
```

Comment: getting error "let is a reserved identifier"

Answer (score 3):

```js
class MyClass {

    myTest() {
      console.log('it works');
    }

    runMyTest() {
      this.myTest();
    }

}

var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.runMyTest();
```

Comment: Your answer will be more useful if you explain your solution.

Comment: Here is no keyword "self" in JavaScript. Only "this"
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: *I* know what you changed and why. But someone who doesn't know about `this` won't. You are just telling the OP do something different (implicitly event) but not explaining *why*. Visitors will learn more if you also provide an explanation, not just code.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyClass {

    myTest() {
      console.log('it works');
    }

    runMyTest() {
      this.myTest();
    }

}

var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.runMyTest();
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyClass(){
    constructor(){
         this.init();
    }

    init(){
         const $this = this;
         this.doSomethigElse();
    }

    doSomethingElse(){
         console.log("It worked!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below is an ideal way to call a function in the same class. if it is NodeJS.

**NodeJS**

```
var self;
class SampleClass {
  constructor(tableName) {
    self = this;
  }
  secondFunction(param) {
    console.log(`called secondFunction with ${param}`)
  }
  firstFunction(param) {
    console.log(`called firstFunction with ${param}`)
    self.secondFunction(param);
  }
  async callableFunction(param) {
    self.firstFunction(param)
  }
};
module.exports = SampleClass
```

**ES-6**

```
class SampleClass {
  constructor(tableName) {
    //empty constructor or fill with what you need on init
  }
  secondFunction(param) {
    console.log(`called secondFunction with ${param}`)
  }
  firstFunction(param) {
    console.log(`called firstFunction with ${param}`)
    this.secondFunction(param);
  }
  async callableFunction(param) {
    this.firstFunction(param)
  }
};

var SampleClassObject = new SampleClass()
SampleClassObject.callableFunction('Argument as string!')
```

Answer (score -2):

Other solution is save the value of variable context `$this` inside other for example in `this`

and for use is `this.anyFunction();`

```
class MyClass {
    myTest() {
      console.log('it works');
    }

    runMyTest() {
      let this=$this;
      this.myTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: $this=this; should be there